# Send custom refereal code to registration in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm passing a referral code that I'm saving to wp_usertmeta with a custom field added in functions.php
So far, so good!

Link to wp register: wp-login.php?action=register&ref=2
I save the referral code with:

```
 <?php $ref = $_GET['ref']?>
```

It works BUT, if i enter a username thats already taken i get the standard error message from WordPress that it's taken.

When this happens the URL reloads to: wp-login.php?action=register and i cant use $_GET['ref']

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to save the `$_GET['ref']` value to a cookie or the PHP session. Once the user is registered, you can refer to the cookie/session to save to the database using the [`user_register`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) action hook. Once it is saved, you should clear this value if it is a cookie unless it is needed for something else to reduce the size of each request.

```
//set the cookie
if ( isset( $_GET['ref'] ) ){
    setcookie( "ref", $_GET['ref'] );
}
```

Then save the value using the action hook

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'my_user_register' );
function my_user_register( $user_id ){
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE['ref'] ) ){
        // save the ref to the user meta
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'ref', $_COOKIE['ref'] );
        // delete the cookie
        setcookie( "ref", null, -1 );
    }
}
```